# PayPal API - get amount of fee deducted from payout to account

Tags: paypal

I am using PayPal Pro on a Shopify webstore. Is there a way to use the PayPal API to query my account and get a list of incoming deposits that would show the customer name, total sale, the fee deducted, and the net deposit?

Answer (score 1):

The exact call you need is: https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/api/merchant/GetTransactionDetails_API_Operation_NVP/

But first you need a general idea how to use the API: start with https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/api/gs_PayPalAPIs/

There may be other ways to do this, but I'm (mis)using the PayPal lib included with the PayPal module in PrestaShop 1.6.x, which is based on 106 of the API (current is 204, search for "PayPal AND 'API Version History'" for version details), and it's working fine - I was able to pull fees on my latest transactions.